# How to transform this Regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to figure out what this does, and how to change it.

```
preg_replace('/[^\w\s]/','',$var);
```

I THINK this replaces all symbols with nothing (deletes them basically).  What if I want to allow some specific symbols, what do I change here?

For example I want replace everything EXCEPT:

- /
- numbers
- letters
- spaces

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know php, but usually `[]` defines symbols class, and `^` negates, just add your symbols before `]`.

Comment: Does `^` negate everythingwithin the `[]`?

Comment: As another member mentioned, it negates stuff **after** it and not everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` means everything but this, so this replaces everything but word characters (`\w`) and whitespace (`\s`).

To replace everything except the characters you mention, use this:

```
preg_replace('/[^\w\s\/]/', '', $var);
```

`\/` is the escaped version of `/`.

Comment: What does the `\d` do?  I can confirm that the regex in the original post does NOT replace numbers...

Comment: `\d` means numbers/digits, `\w` means letters (a-z and A-Z).

Comment: \w should include numbers too:

Comment: So really I just need to add `\/` to the end, inside the brackets.

Comment: I just checked, `\w` does indeed match numbers as well, I didn't know that; so yes, you just need to add `\/` - updated the code in my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

that is basically:
"find everything that's not a word character or a space character and remove it from the string"

^ is a negation, so you can put whatever you want after that in the [] and it will skip those.  It is already doing everything you want except for the /

Note : \w is shorthand for [0-9A-Za-z_] (or close to it.)

from a [perl.org](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html)

> \w is a word character (alphanumeric or *) and represents
>       [0-9a-zA-Z*]